# Kinds of jobs that ex-biologist can apply?

Tags: united-states, job-search, south-east-asia

I am in need of some “brainstorming” help/advice for my job search. 
Here is a brief re-cap of my situation: a person from Eastern Europe, did a lack-luster Ph.D with zero supervision or mentorship in Germany. Moved to Canada, spend 3 years at the third-rate university as a "research associate/postdoc" (in reality - as a technician, it was only job I was able to secure after a “bad” PhD). I quit my stay at that university, as soon as I could.

Through my grad. school and research associate I've be doing a lot of standard molecular biology jobs: PCR, DNA isolation, cloning, protein/nucleic electrophoresis, blotting, production and purification of recombinant proteins, genetically modified bacteria... anyway, all this hands-on experience belongs to the landfill now.

Have been working as a project manager at another small university (mainly liaising, talking, sitting on meetings, writing documents /emails). Became a Canadian citizen. My job has nothing to do with the Uni, I am employed there because the Uni is a holder of "grant money" for multi-partner project. Genuinely enjoying the job and people interactions, but this is all “soft-money” position, which gives me very little stability and no bargaining chips whatsoever. Besides that, the situation gets "shaky" in terms of project continuation.

I am thinking about embarking on job search again. Just checked NatureJobs - academic job market is pretty anemic in Canada, nothing new. No biotech either.

A Few big negatives: 
1)  I have no demonstrable record of academic achievement, bunch of useless middle-author papers and one useless book-chapter; 
2)  I've been out of lab for 3 years and no one will hire me do the lab stuff anymore, neither in academia nor in industry R&D; 
3)   I have never taught any courses to students either (the last PI was all too busy using me as a technician);
4)  I am not a native English speaker, so nobody will hire me as a science writer.

I would love to hear your suggestions as to what jobs I can realistically apply to? I would really like to “brainstorm” though the list of job titles/descriptions.

I am thinking about two regions (1) US – it might be easier to get a job as a Canadian and there is a bigger market out there; (2) Lately I thought of going to SE Asia as "English teacher", but can I possibly aim for something better? I know I will not make it into any decent Korean/Japanese University. What about some places in China? Is it worth it? Are there chances of finding a “lecturer” position somewhere in SE Asia?

Any reasonable suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You have Canadian passport and you want to be only English teacher in South East Asia? I think you should reconsider and apply for possition at uni. Especially with your background. Is uni in Germany where you did PhD accredited?

Comment: Yes, it is a legitimate PhD degree in mol.biology with a dissertation available online etc. I don't really want to go into telling about my unfortunate experiences, I try not to despair, but, to tell you the truth, sometimes I want to have some simple mundane boring job which requires minimal brain activity. Maybe, I am undercutting myself... I've looked today at the application procedure at one South Korean Uni - it's plainly ridiculous, they require print outs of all publications, a PhD thesis on a USB stick mailed by a Snail mail. Who does this in 21 century?

Comment: Oh yes, Taiwan, Thailand, Malaysia are also the same, if you will come to SAE you need to know a lot of bureaucracy and nonsense procedures, including school. However, I maybe recommend for you some sort of international demonstration school, or international colleagues or high schools that are private and itnternational. if you dont want academia, salary is also higher

Comment: Do you know of any on-line resources where such job ads are posted? Could you kindly recommend any expat or professional community of people, working at those international schools or colleges that you mentioned? Thank you!

Comment: I think just google https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SQJL_enTH865TH865&sxsrf=ALeKk01MTZp_TG6l3UEqKGU93lsYbYKB4w%3A1583298709865&ei=lThfXqqlNMGb9QPKhIOACw&q=international+demonstration+school+high+school&oq=international+demonstration+school+high+school&gs_l=psy-ab.3...16087.18553..18888...1.3..0.128.1683.0j15......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.my7w5ljQxEE&ved=0ahUKEwjqw7Kph4DoAhXBTX0KHUrCALAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5

Comment: I mean you need to search terms as international demonstration school high school, and than go to each  of school website and apply or send inquiry

Comment: Thank you! As a person, who went through immigration, through uphill battle in job search, I am really anxious about everything and try to do as much due diligence as humanely possible. Went on Indeed ca today, the job market for anything biology is not bad, it is shockingly bad.

Comment: also LinkedIN, it is  really ok situation

Comment: "_all this hands-on experience belongs to the landfill now._". Absolutely NOT. As of now, every bio lab in my location are looking for people who can do this kind of things. I guess you know what COVID-19 is.

Comment: Problem is that OP don't want to be technician or Postdoc. He wants to have tenure job or the job in industry or education. Those are diificult to score in your country @scaaahu if you don't have pedegree

Comment: @SSimon: no, I do not want to have a "tenure job"! No way.  If someone if a tenure-track prof, this means endless and persistent search for funding. In reality this means 24/7 grant writing. I really do not have a stamina for this anymore, with all my respect to people who excel in this race. "Postdoc" is beyond me, as I have been out of lab for >3 years.

Comment: The truth is that CoVID will go away sooner or later, and what will happen with all those lab. people? In all likelihood they will be laid off.

Comment: @user136555 I don't know if CoVID-19 will go away soon or not (I am not bio expert). But, I do know that Taiwan has been trying to develop bio industry, which as you know, requires expertise and experience. So, there are opportunities around here. .

Comment: I do hope that the virus goes away soon (rather sooner, than later) and SE Asia recovers swiftly from its impact. I feel sorry for people. Anyhow, thank you for encouragement I appreciate it - I will definitely do my research on Taiwan industries.

Comment: @user136555 in my experience Taiwan is out of reach for you. I think you have better luck for US and Canada based corporation, honestly, salaries are lower in Taiwan and they accept people with pedegree

Comment: @SSimon Did you mean pedigree? I live close to [Academia Sinica](https://www.sinica.edu.tw/en). There are a lot of foreign researchers around here. And there is a bio industry park about 5 km distance. In my apartment building campus, there are at least 3 Indians. There are also Americans, Europeans and Vietnameses, etc. The name of the road is "Academia Road".

Comment: Google search "Academia road Taipei", you'll find where I live.

Comment: How many are on permanent position?

Comment: @SSimon: thank you! Let me add my 5 cents. There are two reasons why I do not want to "postdoc": 1) if I don't have a "pedigree" to get a tenure-track, there is no point in dragging it further; 2) I've got off Indeed . You know what is the "salary range" for a postdoc? 32k to 50k Canadian! That's approx. 24K to 37K US dollars. I never heard of anyone who got 50k, though. Usually, its around 40K Canadian. In my opinion, its just "scraping by". Than factor in ~50-60 hr work-week and it gets really ugly.

Comment: @SSimon: speaking of Taiwan and other countries. You know what is the problem for people like me? We are "overqualified, but under-experienced". Industry experience beats academic experience any day and every day. One has to make a jump somehow, somewhere to start getting that experience. This is the tough part. I am in the limbo right now. I am not a "postdoc", but a "project manager" at the undergrad teaching uni.

Comment: You know, one has to get on a "career track", start building that portfolio of achievements; start crafting a resume instead of academic CV. I got to offer something of value to prospective employer (well, everyone has to). And it very mentally draining to know that there is very little you can actually offer.

Comment: @user136555 Taiwan is not for you and SEA you can however work and make a lot of money in an international schools,